# AudioRecord produces choppy audio

Tags: android, audio-streaming, audio-recording, audiorecord, audioformat

I am using AudioRecord to capture audio packets and stream them to a voice recognition server.
In my Galaxy Note 4, Android M device, it works perfectly fine.
However, when I use other devices (Nexus 7/Android L and HTC combo/android ICS) the resulting audio is choppy, with glitchy noises in the sound every half a second that spoil the speech recognition process at the server.

I know this is a complicated topic, does somebody know how to deal with this audio capture irregularities in android?

This is my code setup:

```
private static final int AUDIO_SOURCE =  MediaRecorder.AudioSource.VOICE_RECOGNITION;
private static final int SAMPLING_RATE = 16000; //44100,
private static final int CHANNEL_CONFIG = AudioFormat.CHANNEL_IN_MONO;
private static final int BIT_RATE = AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT;
bufferSize = AudioRecord.getMinBufferSize(SAMPLING_RATE,
                CHANNEL_CONFIG,
                BIT_RATE;
        audioBuffer = new byte[bufferSize]; 
AudioRecord recorder = new AudioRecord(AUDIO_SOURCE, 
                SAMPLING_RATE,
                CHANNEL_CONFIG,
                BIT_RATE,
                bufferSize);
recorder.startRecording();
while (isRecording) {
   short[] buffer = new short[bufferSize];
   int shorts_recorded = recorder.read(buffer, 0, buffer.length);
   byte[] audioBytes = new byte[bufferSize*2]; //bufferSize*2
   ByteBuffer.wrap(audioBytes).order(ByteOrder.LITTLE_ENDIAN).asShortBuffer().put(buffer);//runningBuffer.get(0));
   Integer.toString(audioBytes.length)+","+audioBuffer.length);
   handler.onAudioDataCapture(audioBytes);  //expose audio data to upload callback interface
    proceed();
    }
```

Comment: hum, don't know why you have glitches but you are creating 2 arrays (buffer and audioBytes) inside the loop, you should really avoid that

Comment: `Integer.toString(audioBytes.length)+","+audioBuffer.length);`  I think this line does nothing and can be removed.

Comment: Yeah good idea, it was used to display something on logcat @petey

Comment: what does `proceed()` do?